# How to fix app crash when images and gifs are loaded?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to load 2 gif and 2 images(png) in a specific state but the app crashes after loading some of them so suddenly close the app
I debugged app with android studio and got low memory issues
what can I do for solving this problem?

React Native version: 0.57.2

Platform: Android
Development Operating System: Windows 10

this is just part of my render code

```
 ....
 <Animated.Image
  source={
    this.props.nextDone && this.props.selectedOptionId !== null
      ? gifEndGuage[
          this.state.prvSelectionOptionId * 10 +
            this.props.selectedOptionId
        ]
      : this.props.selectedOptionId !== null
      ? pathsGif[
          this.state.prvSelectionOptionId * 10 +
            this.props.selectedOptionId
        ]
      : this.state.guageImage
  }
  style={{
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    opacity: this.state.gifState
  }}
/>

<Animated.Image
  source={
    this.props.selectedOptionId !== null
      ? pathsPng[this.props.selectedOptionId]
      : this.state.selectedGuagePng
  }
  style={{
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    opacity: this.state.pngState,
    position: 'absolute'
  }}
/>
 ....
```

Comment: `Animated.Image` what package this come from?

Comment: @Vencovsky animated is a package from react native that animated text,view and image